# Likelihood for more people to draw the same number

Tags: probability

Hope this question will describe the situation better.

We have a button which when pushed it returns a totally number random between 1 and 100. So, the probability for each number individually is 1/100 (1%).

Let's assume 1000 people push the button. Individually each person has a 1% chance to draw number 5 independent of the others.

What's the probability of number 5 to be drawn multiple times in this context? How many from those 1000 people could probably draw number 5 assuming the drawing is always totally random.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: "How many ..... could **probably** draw ..... " is totally vague. You can ask for the probability that 3 people, say, draw number 5. (Btw, does repeated independent trials with probability of success 1/100 for each trial, remind you of something ?) Or are you asking for the *expected* number.. ?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

The situation as described can be modelled by the binomial distribution.

Depending on what you have in mind, you can find
(a) the probability that *k* people press 5
(b) the expected number of people who press 5

Do you have no knowledge of the binomial distribution ? Then see the answer, else revise what you have learnt, and try before seeing.

> $P(8\;\text{people press}\;5)= \binom{1000}{8}*0.01^8 *0.99^{992},\approx 0.1128$ 
>  $P(\text{expected # of people press}\;5) = 1000*0.01 = 10$

Comment: Yes that is correct. How do I calculate both a and b? Both are helpful in moving to the next part of the complex problem. thank you very much.

Comment: I have expanded hint to hidden answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry I had javascript disabled. It's my first time using stackexchange so sorry. I had no knowledge of binomial distribution, but under my logic I had the same result for the expected people to draw 5. It is <total number of people drawing> * individual probability for the number = expected people to draw that number. I assume the number is a theoretical maximum, so in practice we should usually see less than this drawing the same number, but it's all chance here so it's not mandatory that it'll be like this.

Comment: Thanks again. I am trying to reproduce (a) but don't come with the right values. So let's say probability for 15 people to draw 5: (1000/15) *0.01 ^15 * 0.99^985 =

Comment: Two points. (1) $\binom{1000}{8}$ is not $1000/8$, it is $1000$ choose $8$ for which there is a formula you can see in the link given. (2) Expected value is not the maximum value, it is the average # expected if the experiment is repeated many times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: thank you. I have printed the wikipedia page - it's very interesting and makes a lot more sense now. what i can't find there is the explanation of the formula, it only gives the formula and the result. how do i calculate 1000 choose 15 for example, separately, to get to the same result? i can't find the info for expanding the formula. i want to be able to calculate the likelihood with many different numbers.

Comment: I am giving a link which will explain in detail. http://www.wtamu.edu/academic/anns/mps/math/mathlab/col_algebra/col_alg_tut57_comb.htm